# CarouselView in Xamarin Shared Project

Tags: xamarin, carousel, portable-class-library, shared-project

I'm using this third party component
[CarouselView](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView)

The instructions are clear if using a PCL for the main project but I happened to start my solution with a shared project.

My problem is that I can't get the assembly and namespace to load for the xaml found in the shared project.

I created a test project that used a PCL and I was able to easily get it working.

My question is, can this plugin work with Xamarin Shared project?

Comment: Man did you get the answer , me too stuck @mac

Comment: @idris stack: I stopped using a shared project and went to pcl

Comment: What!!!,  but seems my VS17 on Mac doesnt show PCL , what can i do ?

Comment: It's there somewhere. I'm using vs on Mac too. Never used windows for the project

Comment: Ok ve seen , so the CarouselView worked well on PCL

Comment: Ok ve seen , so the CarouselView worked well on PCL